# jQuery Mobile custom select not closing

Tags: jquery-mobile, select, menu

I have a web application which uses jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.0b3. I need to display a list of options, so I used a custom select. I cannot close the select by using the header button, and neither by selecting an option.

The nativeMenu = false is set globally.
I create the select using

```
 <select data-mini="true">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
  </select>
```

The HTML look like this (there are many more options, so the select goes full-screen):

```
   <div data-role="dialog" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="a" tabindex="0"
    class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-dialog ui-overlay-a ui-page-active" style="min-height: 480px;">
      <div role="dialog" class="ui-dialog-contain ui-corner-all ui-overlay-shadow">
        <div data-role="header" class="ui-corner-top ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
          <a href="#" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext"
          class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true"
          data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" title="Close">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
              <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
          </a>
          <div class="ui-title"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-c" role="main">
          <ul class="ui-selectmenu-list ui-listview" id="undefined-menu" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="undefined-button"
          data-theme="c">
            <li data-option-index="0" data-icon="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-active ui-btn-up-c"
            role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div"
            data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="true">
              <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                  <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">Option1</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-option-index="1" data-icon="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-c" role="option"
            data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right"
            data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
              <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                  <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">Option2</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>       
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The header button works with jQuery 1.8.3 & jQm 1.2.1 (selecting an option still doesn't work), but changing this versions leads to other problems in my legacy app, so I would prefer a solution for 1.6.2 & jQm 1.0. 
 Any ideas why the select doesn't work ?

EDIT:
  After a couple of days of searching, I found out that the dialog doesn't close because I have set hashListeningEnabled = false. Unfortunately, I cannot change this. I stumbled upon this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2285, but I cannot upgrade the jQm/jQuery version. So I'm left with finding some good alternative for the select. Any suggestions ?

Comment: what do you mean by _header button_? Menu closes once an option is selected. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7vFqs/

Comment: if you work with a long selectmenu, a dialog popups up with list of options. I never worked on 1.6.4, but you could try this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7vFqs/

Comment: It doesn't work for a full-screen custom select (not by selecting an option and neither by clicking the header button).

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to assist you in this issue.

Comment: @Omar: I've tried you solution, binding the change event, and it works. However, it doesn't solve the header button issue and if the selection is not changed, the menu still remains open. So I don't want a workaround, I want to figure out what's wrong in my code that breaks down the default behaviour provided by jQm.

Answer (score 0):

wow... no answer to this... almost one year bfore! and i have the same (or actually similar... soon enough) issue. So here i go with my experience:

(in which i need to mention that i am able to select multiple items but when i hit the cross button over the header... no closing action will follow. so DANG!

i have been trying to figure some kind of workaround for this.. so i started mutating some other jQm pop ups and the problem that i'm facing now is that my solution seems to show different buttons with the  html object (each time you click this one only button it goes round the SELECT's items displaying them one at a time inside this one button, very weird... at least for my rookie experience with jquery mobile, so maybe its a simple couple of options that i didnt kneew how to set, but im being blind to the solution.

So, what do i need to show a nice popup like the one in the picture (also code pasted below) from a common SELECT (HTML OBJECT) ?

[image: Nice and beautiful select inside a jqm that WONT CLOSE WHEN YOU CLICK THE CROSS LINK]

(please take a look of what i intent to achive (the look and feel) 
h t t p : / / i . s t a c k . i m g u r . c o m /I5q0I.png

And this is the code that i should have (but with the cross working, which is not.)

```
            <div class="ui-popup-container ui-popup-active" id="select-choice-7458-listbox-popup" tabindex="0" style="max-width: 1825px; top: 2788.5px; left: 805.5px;">
                <div id="select-choice-7458-listbox" class="ui-selectmenu ui-popup ui-body-a ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all">
                    <div class="ui-header ui-bar-c">
                        <h1 class="ui-title">

                        </h1>
                        <a href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" title="Close">
                            <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                                <span class="ui-btn-text">
                                    Close
                                </span>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;</span>

                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="ui-selectmenu-list ui-listview" id="select-choice-7458-menu" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="select-choice-7458-button" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="b">
                        <li data-option-index="0" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-placeholder="true" class="ui-selectmenu-placeholder ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-first-child" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit"></a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-option-index="1" data-icon="checkbox-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">
                                        Scribbling</a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-option-index="2" data-icon="checkbox-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">
                                        Letter-like symbols</a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-option-index="3" data-icon="checkbox-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">
                                        Strings of letters</a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-option-index="4" data-icon="checkbox-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">
                                        Beginning sounds
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-option-index="5" data-icon="checkbox-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">
                                        Ending and medial sounds
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-option-index="6" data-icon="checkbox-off" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="ui-link-inherit">
                                        Conventional writing
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```